# Can we copy "checkbox" along with text to clipboard?

Tags: html

I'm using clipboard.js to implement the copy-to-clipboard feature in my app, I have content with a checkbox that I would like to copy along with text, is that even possible?

```html
<div>
      <input type="checkbox">Electricity Bill
 </div>
```

This will show a checkbox followed by text in the browser, I want to copy it as it is and paste it into Word document, with a functional checkbox!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. HTML and Word checkboxes are entirely different.